# PHP Sort multi-dimension array by keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi dimension array like below:

```
Array 
   (
   [1200] => Array 
      (
      [B] => Array
         (
         [4] => Array
             (
             [Name] => 'Joe']
             )
         )
      [A] => Array
         (
         [3] => Array
             (
             [Name] => 'Paul']
             )
         )
      )
   [1100] => Array 
      (
      [F] => Array
         (
         [2] => Array
             (
             [Name] => 'Sam']
             )
         )
      [D] => Array
         (
         [1] => Array
             (
             [Name] => 'Jane']
             )
         )
      )
```

What I wish to achieve is having the 4 digit number 1100 and 1200 in order ascending, then I need the letters (B A) and (F D) also in order, and then the single digit number under them in order ascending too. I believe I'm looking at a multi dimension array but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below function might be what you're looking for. It recursively orders arrays by their key.

```php
function ksort_r(&$array) {
   foreach ($array as &$value) {
      if (is_array($value)) {
          ksort_r($value);
      }
   }
   return ksort($array);
}
```

**Example usage**

```php
function ksort_r(&$array) {
   foreach ($array as &$value) {
      if (is_array($value)) {
          ksort_r($value);
      }
   }
   return ksort($array);
}

$data = [
    1200 => [
        'B' => [
            4 => [
                'Name' => 'Joe'
            ]
        ],
        'A' => [
            3 => [
                'Name' => 'Paul'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    1100 => [
        'F' => [
            2 => [
                'Name' => 'Sam'
            ]
        ],
        'D' => [
            1 => [
                'Name' => 'Jane'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

ksort_r($data);

print_r($data);
```

The above will output...

```
Array
(
    [1100] => Array
        (
            [D] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => Jane
                        )

                )

            [F] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => Sam
                        )

                )

        )

    [1200] => Array
        (
            [A] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => Paul
                        )

                )

            [B] => Array
                (
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => Joe
                        )

                )

        )

)
```